# Изменить цвет фона кнопки при клике, и обратно после клика на другую кнопку

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

Есть три кнопки, при нажатии у каждой свой цвет.
Но проблема в том, что я нажимаю на 1 - цвет активен, жму на 2 - тоже цвет активен.
А надо, чтобы нажал на 2 и у 1 цвет пропал.

Вот мой код:

```js
$('.first').click(function(){
 $('#active1').css('background-color', '#339999');
})

$('.firsts').click(function(){
 $('#active2').css('background-color', '#339933');
}) 
 
$('.firstss').click(function(){
 $('#active3').css('background-color', '#993399');
})
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: "Poppins", Arial;
/*  background-color: #a7a6a6; */
}
.menu {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 50px;
 display: flex;
}
.menu button {
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.firsts {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="first"><button id="active1">6</button></div>
  <div class="firsts"><button id="active2">12</button></div>
  <div class="firstss"><button id="active3">24</button></div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.first').click(function() {
  function storeColor(aBtn) {
    var originalColor = $(aBtn).data("originalcolor");
    if (!originalColor) {
      originalColor = window.getComputedStyle(aBtn).backgroundColor;
      $(aBtn).data("originalcolor", originalColor);
    }
    return originalColor;
  }
  function resetColor(aBtn) {
    var originalColor = storeColor(aBtn);
    $(aBtn).css('background-color', originalColor);
  }
  function setColor(aBtn) {
    storeColor(aBtn);
    var newColor = $(aBtn).data("backcolor");
    $(aBtn).css('background-color', newColor);
  }

  $(".first button").each(function(){
    resetColor(this);
  });
  setColor($(this).find("button")[0]);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Poppins", Arial;
  /*  background-color: #a7a6a6; */
}

.menu {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.menu button {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="first"><button data-backcolor="#339999">6</button></div>
  <div class="first"><button data-backcolor="#339933">12</button></div>
  <div class="first"><button data-backcolor="#993399">24</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: @BogdanMakarenko Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @BogdanMakarenko А знак "помогло" - стрелочка вверх слева от ответа.

Comment: @0xdb Только после того как Вы проголосуете за вопрос ), и репутация автора достигнет значения 15.

Comment: @Igor Да, знаю. У мыши батарейка села, поменял.